# Web UI for Custom C# App

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a application written in C#, installed as a [WCF] windows service, which will be running on headless machines.  I would like to provide a nice web UI for it, but I'm not sure how to host it.  After looking at embedded web servers such as Cassini, none seem ready for this without a ton of web server code.  I would like to find a package that would let me design in something like Silverlight.  Also, I need to be able to provide a simple installer for customers that doesn't involve "go get IIS", etc.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813192/silverlight-as-front-end-for-business-application) that seemed close, but didn't really answer any of my questions, except affirming that its possible.  I'm really looking for specifics on how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why go silver-light route unless you need very rich/flexible UI? I would suggest using WCF itself to serve HTML over HttpBinding. Have a look at few articles regarding the same:

http://blog.iserviceoriented.com/index.php/2010/01/23/building-a-basic-web-server-using-wcf/

[How do I create a simple Web Server using WCF without the ServiceHost class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159213/how-do-i-create-a-simple-web-server-using-wcf-without-the-servicehost-class)

REST support by System.ServiceModel.Web namespace should make the task even more simpler (than described in above articles).